# Matching game in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

Im making a GUI matching game on Java, I want to make it so that when a duplicate button is pressed, it changes to a color other than orange. For example, if there's 2 buttons on the gameboard labelled "6", i'd want it to change those buttons to the color blue rather than orange

Any help would be appreciated.

Heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class link extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ 

  JPanel panel1, panel2,panel3,panel4,panel5,panel6;
  JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11;
  JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9; 
  JButton Reset;
  int da=0;
  int ea=0;
  int ra=0;
  int grass=0;
  String track= "";
  String rack="";
  int fly=0;
  int counter=5;
  int count=0;
  int winner=0;
  Color blue;
  Color orange;
  Color lime;
  JButton[]linx=new JButton[53];
  int workspaceWidth=1200, workspaceHeight=800;
  public static void main(String[ ] args) 
  {
    new link();
  }  

  public link(){
    blue=new Color(19, 196, 255);
    orange= new Color(255, 33, 44);
    orange= new Color(255, 89, 0);
    lime= new Color(110, 255, 110);
    panel1=new JPanel();
    panel2=new JPanel();
    panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    Font buttons= new Font("Bahnschrift", Font.BOLD, 25);
    Font apples= new Font("Bahnschrift", Font.BOLD, 20);

    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,6)); // Sets Grid Layout
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4)); // Sets Grid Layout

    for(int q=0;q<52;q++)
    {
    da= (int)(Math.random()*20)+1; 
    linx[q]=new JButton(""+da);
    linx[q].addActionListener (this);
    linx[q].setFont(apples);
    linx[q].setOpaque(true);
    linx[q].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    linx[q].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel1.add(linx[q]);  
    }    

    Reset=new JButton("Reset");
    Reset.addActionListener (this);
    Reset.setFont(apples);
    Reset.setOpaque(true);
    Reset.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    Reset.setBackground(blue);    
    panel1.add(Reset);  

    l1=new JLabel("  "+counter+" Tries left");
    l1.setOpaque(false);
    l1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    l1.setFont(buttons);
    panel1.add(l1);   

    panel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);  

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    this.add(panel1);
    this.setSize(workspaceWidth,workspaceHeight);
    this.setSize(1100,600);
    this.setVisible(true); 
  } 

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    for(int q=0;q<53;q++)
    {
    if(e.getSource()==linx[q])
    {
     linx[q].setBackground(orange);
     l1.setText("  "+counter--+" Tries left");
    if(linx[q].getText().equals[q]&&linx[q].getText().equals[q])
    {
      System.out.print("track ");
    }
    }
    }

    if(counter==0)
    {
    for(int q=0;q<53;q++)
    {
      l1.setText("  "+"You Lost");
      l1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
      linx[q].setEnabled(false);
    }
    }  

  if(winner==36)
  {
   l1.setText("  "+"You Won");
   l1.setForeground(lime);
  }



    if(e.getSource()==Reset)
    {
    for(int q=0;q<53;q++)
    {
      linx[q].setEnabled(true);
      linx[q].setBackground(Color.BLACK);    
      counter=5;
      l1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      l1.setText("  "+counter+" Tries left");
    }
    }

    }
 }
```

Comment: It would help if you could reduce the question to just the location where you are stuck.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], so we can better understand where is your mistake. Don't post your complete code, but rather create a small example, that demonstrates your problem. Your current code have too much logic, and has no main method to run it. IMHO: to develop a game using Swing you need some years expirience in this framework. So I would start to learn java examples.